# Error innecesario en Visual studio code con laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vscode

Hola comunidad tengo un muy molesto problema con la extensión **PHP Intelephense** en visual studio code

Me dice `Undefined type 'Route'` lo cual es innecesario la verdad ya que laravel funciona muy bien sin la necesidad de definir el `use` para este *namespace* en el archivo de rutas

Tengo entendido que este es un problema bastante popular entre los desarrolladores de Laravel pero, podrían ayudarme a solucionarlo y que *Intelephense* continué con su normal funcionamiento, solo que ignore este error en especifico

Muchas gracias de antemano colegas

Comment: deberias preguntarle a la gente que desarrollo ese plugin tal vez?

Comment: Bueno creo que es una excelente idea, primero verificare si nadie a reportado este problema a su repositorio en _Github_ @gbianchi

Comment: Has intentado solucionarlo con `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`

Comment: @HammerffallBK No tengo conocimiento de ello disculpa, podrías explicarme

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando laravel y quieres remove la importación de los Facades, puedes utilizar este paquete en dev, para generar una lista con esas clases que reconozca vscode.

`composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`

Una vez instalado esto, puedes correr el comando

`php artisan ide-helper:generate`

y tendras un archivo `_ide_helper.php`

Sin _ide_helper.php

[image: Esta es la captura sin _ide_helper.php]

Con _ide_helper.php

[image: Con _ide_helper.php]

Aqui la página del paquete.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#automatic-phpdoc-generation-for-laravel-facades

Comment: @Hammeffall BK estoy obteniendo un error de **composer** al instalar este paquete `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` mi version de laravel es la 6.20